# add class to each table th except the first using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble adding a class to all the "th" except the first ones in every table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I'm using jQuery to do this:

```
$("th").not(":eq(0)").addClass("info");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
$('table th').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('info');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wr1ua0db/1530/

change this: `$("th").not(":eq(0)").addClass("info");`

to this: `$("th").not(":nth-child(1)").addClass("info");`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
$("table").each(function(){
$(this).find("th").not(":eq(0)").addClass("info")
})
```